# tor api in own project

Tags: tor

I'm going to develop gui-based application for tor controlling (like vidalia or torK). Are there any libraries for using tor? I don't want to parse each byte of information from sockets.
My program should display branches of computers, use chosen as traffic-provider etc.
What I need in my case? Are there any small and simple samples (for example open-source projects) to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for example open-source projects

like Vidalia or TorK, you mean? ;-)

Seriously though, I think the best way to start is to download the source code of one of those projects and start picking through it. I wouldn't count on getting something much simpler than that... if it exists, I don't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

[txtorcon](http://github.com/meejah/txtorcon) provides Twisted-based Python bindings to the control protocol, and abstractions to track Tor's state (circuits, streams) and configuration.